# How do I create an array of ascending and then descending numbers?

Tags: c#, arrays

For example:

I have min and max values and a number of increments which may be odd or even;

if I have min = 3 and max = 10 and increments = 15 then I want:

```
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3
```

However, if increments = 16 I want (notice the two 10's in the middle):

```
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3
```

I have to create these arrays add-hoc using just min, max, and number of increments.

UPDATE:

To make this clearer the number of increments is equal to the number of items that must be in the array and the items are decimals.

so if min = 5.0 and max = 15.0 and increments = 6 then the array would contain:

```
5.0, 10.0, 15.0, 15.0, 10.0, 5.0
```

Comment: Can you use LINQ or are you supposed to be doing this "by hand"?

Comment: Is it your homework ?

Comment: @Yuck: Linq is ok to use

Comment: whats the output for min = 3 and max = 10 and increments = 20

Comment: i imagine the question goes like this. the min,max, increment input must be such so you can loop back to min, and if the count getting you to max is over half way then max is not repeated, otherwise it is. so some combinations or min,max,incr are invalid, like 3,10,20. but who know, we are left to guess !

Comment: So if you had something like `min=5`, `max=14`, `increments=7`, the resultant list would be `5, 8, 11, 14, 11, 8, 5`?

Comment: @descf answer roughnex please.

Comment: @nawfal: an array of doubles

Comment: @descf fine, now as a last step, tell us how far you have gone with the code..

Answer (score 1):

Linq way:

```
int min = 3;
int max = 10;
int increments = 15;

Enumerable
    .Range(min, max - min + 1)
    .Concat(Enumerable
        .Range(min, max - min + 1)
        .Reverse()
        .Skip(increments % 2))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: hi, I've updated the information given with the question to try and make the problem a bit clearer

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
public static IEnumerable<decimal> NewMethod(decimal min, decimal max, int count)
{
    var increment = (max - min) / (int)((count - 1) / 2);

    for (var i = min; i < max; i += increment)
        yield return i;

    if (count % 2 == 0)
        yield return max;

    for (var i = max; i >= min ; i -= increment)
        yield return i;
}
```

Sample test:

```
var min = 3.0m;
var max = 10.0m;
var count = 16;

MessageBox.Show(string.Join(", ", NewMethod(min, max, count)));
```

**Edit:** You have to cope with floating point types losing precision, otherwise you will be missing an element in the final result set. Tinker a bit with `Math.Round` over the `i +=` and `i -=` part, that's up to you. I have updated code to replace `double` with more reliable `decimal` type. But there is no guarantee this should not fail every time. Easier is to avoid cases where you will need decimal types in the result like `{ 1, 2.2, 3.4 }` etc.

Comment: Gimme an example set pls..  I mean what are the min and max?

Comment: just change count to 7 or 8, everything else stays the same

Comment: @descf you're running into precision errors, bound to happen with floating point arithmetics. Do you really want fractional values? Its easier and safer to avoid them in the first place.. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-way ramp that handles floating point values correctly.  You should be able to modify it to make a triangle waveform.  When implementing a ramp, care must be taken to make sure not to accumulate either round-off errors, or off-by-one errors for various inputs.

```
void Packet::SetRamp( const SampleType start /*= Signal::One*/,
                      const SampleType finish /*= -Signal::One */ )
{
    SampleType slope, current;
    SampleOffsetType len;
    len = GetLength();
    if ( len < 2 )
        throw std::range_error( "packet is not large enough to set ramp into" );
    slope = ( finish - start ) / ( len - 1 );
    for ( SampleOffsetType row = 0; row < len; row++ )
    {
        current = slope * row + start;
        SetSample( row, current );
    }
}
```