# Calculate Different Percentages Of Number In Textbox1 and display in textbox2 and 3

Tags: c#, textbox

I have a C# Windows Form "tax" type calculator and would like to know how I would take the number entered into "textbox1" and work out .95 of that number and display it in textbox2 and work out the other .05 and display that in textbox3. I know you could use labels, but textboxes fit in with the project more.

Comment: Is this your homework?

Comment: We are not here to write code for you, so if you tried something and it didn't work, post it, otherwise you aren't in the right place.

Comment: if it worked for you, you should say it did or didn't and accept the question after the time has passed

Comment: @Fuex for me I find it best to ask the question, get an answer and then go over the answer and work out it out, sorry if it seems I am lazy,

Comment: Itdsvery lazy and your question is basic maths from when children first start learning about percentages. What is there to go over?

Comment: @Sayse, I can work this out in my head as well, what do you think I'm incapable of it? This is for learning experience.

Comment: But what have you learned? Georgi-it just did it for you

Comment: @Sayse, now I have learnt how to apply percentages from a textbox to other textboxes. Now, I can read over it and understand it more.

Comment: [Convert Number to String](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=convert+string+to+number+c%23&oq=convert+string+to+number+c%23&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l3j62l2.4512j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and [Convert String to number](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=convert+number+to+string+c%23&oq=convert+number+to+string+c%23&aqs=chrome.0.57j0j61j0l2j62.5331j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), the fact that I was able to find the answer to your real question in less than 5 seconds, and your comments under your question, proves that you had never intended to learn anything

Comment: @Sayse Other people seemed to have moved on from this, I'm trying to work out why you keep insisting that I have no intentions of learning. Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work if i understood your question

```
double number = int.Parse(textbox1.Text);
double _95Percentage = number * 95 / 100;
double _05Percentage = number - _95Percentage;
textbox2.Text = _95Percentage.ToString();
textbox3.Text = _05Percentage.ToString();
```

EDIT: if you want your calculations to be 100% accurate replace double with decimal.

Comment: decimals wont be 100% accurate as well :)

Comment: yes it will, i think, it's made for money so it should be

Comment: where exactly in the code would this be implemented?

Comment: on a button click...., if you don't know this you shouldn't be asking us but reading tutorials

Comment: Depending on the compiler, * 0.95 would be more more efficient ;)

Comment: @georgi-it no it wont be. do `var d = 10m; var division = d / 3;` wouldn't you see some loss in `division` variable? `decimal` is no magic, but more bits used to store more info. Just that its precision is much higher than `double` and `float` and you will be able to workout better results. See [this Jon's link](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx) too. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570347/how-do-i-create-an-array-of-ascending-and-then-descending-numbers/16572625#16572625) too for a practical problem

Comment: @Georgi-it, I asked because I don't want to have a button to calculate it, rather it just calculate as you type.

Comment: @Sayse the compiler will optimize it. I mean will precompute it.

Comment: @Fadzitt then you should use `TextChanged` event of text box.

Comment: @nawfal I'm aware of that, I don't believe all compilers will though

Comment: All compilers? How many compilers do you think there are for c#, it's just microsoft's and thats all.